# What is "Microsoft Office (2 files) - Version: 15.0.4420.1017" plugin?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-integration, chrome

Does anyone know what exactly the "Microsoft Office (2 files) - Version: 15.0.4420.1017" plugin does in Chrome? I can't find any documentation on this.

I see this on Windows machines when I use Chrome or Firefox with SharePoint Online (Office 365).

Answer (score 2):

The plugin allows you to have a better experience with Microsoft SharePoint

Typical file path:  C:\Program Files\microsoft office 15\root\office15\npspwrap.dll

Mozilla plugins

- Microsoft SharePoint Plug-in for Firefox

Google Chrome plugins

- Stored per user in the directory 'Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences'
- Name: 'NPSPWRAP.DLL'

NPSPWRAP.dll is a dynamic link-library (DLL) that is installed in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office*\ directory on the client computer during Microsoft Office Setup. Its purpose is similar to that of the OpenDocuments control, except that it is designed to work in a Firefox web browser. For more information, see [OpenDocuments Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454230(v=office.14).aspx).

In SharePoint Foundation, you add the control to a webpage by calling the CreateFirefoxOnWindowsPlugin function in the INIT.js. This call adds an OBJECT element to the Document Object Model (DOM) of the hosting page using application/x-sharepoint as the value of the type property. This is the MIME type of the plug-in.

Comment: Ok, but what does it do? If this plugin is not installed, what happens? Is something broken?

Comment: I can't find any documentation which exactly explains what all it does. From what I understand is since ActiveX is not supported in FireFox/Chrome, Microsoft has created this plugin to render Office documents in non-IE browsers.

Comment: Amal's answer appears to come from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407576%28v=office.14%29.aspx